# What is causing the error "Column does not match the value count at row 1"?

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL Code:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_ORDERS (
        TOTAL_HANDLED INT,
        CONSTRAINT PK_TOTAL PRIMARY KEY (TOTAL_HANDLED)
        );

        INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_ORDERS (
        SELECT COUNT(ORDERS.EMPLOYEE_ID), EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID
        FROM ORDERS LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE
        ON ORDERS.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID
        GROUP BY EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID
        ORDER BY COUNT(ORDERS.EMPLOYEE_ID));
```

I've attempted: INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_ORDERS (TOTAL_HANDLED) (SELECT....

I'm trying to return the ID of all employees who have handled more than 0 orders, any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: You are selecting too many or too little columns. Specify the columns and values you would like to insert like so: ```INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_ORDERS (`column1`, `column2`, ...) VALUES (value1, value2); ```

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery is returning two values, but you only have one column in the table. You need to rewrite your subquery to get rid of the `COUNT` value and use it in a `HAVING` clause to filter the employee ids:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_ORDERS
    SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID
    FROM ORDERS 
    LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE ON ORDERS.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID
    GROUP BY EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID
    HAVING COUNT(ORDERS.EMPLOYEE_ID) > 0
```

Note there is no point having an `ORDER BY` in your subquery as it won't have any effect on the rows inserted into the table.

Note also that by replacing the `LEFT JOIN` with a `JOIN` and swapping the order of the tables you will automatically only get employees that have 1 or more matching orders, thus allowing you to simplify the query:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_ORDERS
    SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    JOIN ORDERS ON ORDERS.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a employee-list comparison of the order table with a return of employees with an order count above 0, I'd probably do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp.Employee_ID
          ,     COUNT(Order_ID)
FROM ORDERS ord
RIGHT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEES emp ON emp.Employee_ID = ord.Employee_ID
GROUP BY emp.Employee_ID
HAVING COUNT(Order_ID) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to return the ID of all employees who have handled more than 0 orders

In other words, you just want employees who are in the `ORDERS` table.  Probably the best method is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.EMPLOYEE_ID
FROM ORDERS o
```

If you want the count as well, use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT o.EMPLOYEE_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM ORDERS o
GROUP BY o.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

No `JOIN` is necessary.  The employees that you are looking for are already in `ORDERS`.